# I'm having an issue saving a new User with password_digest information. ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passwords

I'm fairly new to Rails and have recently created an end to end simple application, with a Rails backend and a front end iOS app that consume my backend JSON API.

I have no problem creating data via a POST for all my models.

However, I've recently decided to add a User model (as per Hartl's tutorial), and I can't seem to create a new entry via Postman. Here's what I've got...

api/v1/users_controller.rb

```
module Api
    module V1
        class UsersController < ApplicationController
            respond_to :json
            skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token

            def show
                @user = User.find(params[:id])
                respond_with (@user)
            end

            def create
                @user = User.new(params[user_params])
                if @user.save!
                    respond_with (@user)
                else

                end
            end

            private

                def user_params
                    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
                end
        end
    end
end
```

And models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_save { self.email = email.downcase }

    validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, 
                      uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

    has_secure_password
    validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
end
```

I fire up my server, and post the following via PostMan...

```
{
    "user": 
        {
            "name": "Johnny",
            "email": "J@J.com",
            "password": "aaaaaa",
            "password_confirmation": "aaaaaa"
        }
}
```

But i get this output on the server...

```
Started POST "/api/v1/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-13 09:04:23 -0700
Processing by Api::V1::UsersController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"name"=>"Johnny", "email"=>"J@J.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."email" IS NULL LIMIT 1
   (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 12ms

ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Name can't be blank, Email can't be blank, Email is invalid, Password can't be blank, Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)):
  app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb:14:in `create'
```

If I change save! to save, I get...

```
Started POST "/api/v1/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-13 09:06:09 -0700
Processing by Api::V1::UsersController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"name"=>"Johnny", "email"=>"J@J.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (1.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."email" IS NULL LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 95ms

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template api/v1/users/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/Developer/RUBY/iOSandRails/hotelDemo/app/views"
):
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line in the controller

```
@user = User.new(params[user_params])
```

to

```
@user = User.new(user_params)
```

`user_params` is a method, not an item of the params array.